# Multiple imports of bootstrap in an angular application

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular12

When I compile my angular application I get the following error:

```
498 │ $input-height-inner-quarter:            add($input-line-height * .25em, $input-padding-y / 2) !default;
    │                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
    ..\..\..\..\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_variables.scss 498:73  @import
    ..\..\..\..\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss 9:9      @import
    ..\..\..\styles\bootstrap.scss 7:9                              root stylesheet
```

The only saas script I've included is the `styles\bootstrap.scss` which in turn imports bootstrap:

```css
$body-bg: #fff;
$body-color: #111;
$blue: #2a5291 ;
$red: #b20d1c;
$gray: rgba(0,0,0,.1) ;

@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

That script is included in `angular.json`:

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/bootstrap.scss"
            ],
```

I've searched my entire project and cannot find any other place where bootstrap is imported. So why do I get those warnings? Is it automatically included in some way?

Answer (score 0):

When you include any styles in angular.json, then they become part of your project's global style. Any imports that you made in that style file will also be added to your global styles.

Hence when you added `styles\bootstrap.scss` in styles tag in angular.json (which included bootstrap node module), that got added to your project's global style and hence you are getting those warnings.

This warnings appear because sass team has deprecated / in favour of math.div

You can migrate to **bootstrap v5.0.2** to avoid these warnings.